# Sci-fi book with the title "On"

Tags: story-identification

I have a library client looking for a ScFi book he has read before, that he is sure is titled simply "On".  It is about gravity shifting 90 degrees. We have not been able to find it, either in our collection or online.  Does anyone recognise this title, and perhaps know the author?

Comment: Relevant [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/417/).

Comment: I don't want to be overly negative, but the search term "on" on Wikipedia would have brought you to [a page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On) where the book is mentioned as the third link from the top.

Comment: Sorry, I'm downvoting because Moyli's right. This is really easy to find and SFF is not meant to be a search engine replacement.

Comment: duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16731/trying-to-identify-a-book-about-life-on-the-side-of-an-infinitely-tall-wall

Answer (score 32):

Adam Roberts, ["On"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_%28novel%29)

> The story follows the life of an adolescent named Tighe (pronounced,
> roughly, Tig-Hee). Tighe's village is built on the ledges and crags of
> an enormous cliff-face, called the Wall or the World-wall. Every
> morning, the sun rises from the bottom of the wall, and every evening
> it sets at the top.
>
> ...gravity once pointed towards the centre of the earth, but catastrophically changed due to mankind's over-dependence on Zero Point Energy as an energy source.

[image]